# Google Fusion Table Formula

Tags: formula, google-fusion-tables, conditional-statements

I have a Google Fusion table and I am trying to add a formula column with a simple if statement.

The column `TYPE` contains numbers 1-5.  I want to update a formula column based on the value in the `TYPE` column.

I tried many variations (single quote, double quote, etc) of the following:

```
IF(TYPE=1,'red','yellow')
```

But, it always says invalid formula.  If statements are permitted and I am following the format described here: https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/178196?hl=en

What am I missing?

Comment: It sure would be nice if they provided examples that worked...wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formulas only work with numeric columns and must produce numeric results. So if('TYPE'=1, 1, 2) would work. You can add your vote to this issue: https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=235

Answer (score 0):

It works like this IF(TYPE=1,"red","yellow")

Comment: please provide more details on how your answer solves the problem

Comment: **Formula** if(TYPE=1, "red", "yellow") 
**Format** None