# how to format time in fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have a fusion table with the following in my Time Column. basically time entered in hh:mm:ss format. I have a am/pm column with the following formula and it is not working:

```
    if ('Time' > '12:00:00', 'pm', 'am')
```

I am getting all **** instead of pm or am. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry at present it's not possible, have a look at the following two links:

[Google Fusion Table Formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405446/google-fusion-table-formula)

https://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/detail?id=235